# Missing spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-cassandra update in Einstein.M1 Pre-release of Spring Cloud Stream App Starters

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-data-cassandra

Is it unmaintained since verion 1.3.1.RELEASE?

https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/app-starters-release/releases/tag/vEinstein.M1

Is a release planned soon?

https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/cassandra/commit/b1deb62252f23219ff5f72392e3d5d2de2aac6a1

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting it. We are discussing the options at [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/cassandra#10](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/cassandra/issues/10). In the furture, it'd be great if you can avoid duplicate posts.